# Why am I seeing Sql Error 1105 in my Azure Sql Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, transaction-log

I have a database hosted in Azure Sql and am seeing a critical 1105 error.  This error occurs whenever my transaction needs more space than is available in the transaction log.  According to the documentation, whenever this occurs, all active transactions in the database are terminated.  I have looked at metrics during the times the errors occur (they are infrequent), and used space is very close to allocated space.  In one example, the used space was 1.6 gb and the amount allocated was 1.7 gb.  The max size of the database is set to 1 TB.

My first thought is that Azure sql is a managed platform and should automatically be allocating more space as the transaction log grows.  I am surprised to be seeing this error, but I don't know how to resolve it.  The transaction log is managed behind the scenes by Azure. My second thought is that maybe this error is a false positive and possibly an artifact of all the autonomous operations that happen behind the scenes by Azure?

I'm really in the dark, and I have not found much information on the web regarding the 1105 error in an Azure Sql DB.

Comment: For this question, I suggest you ask Azure Support for help on Portal for your Azure  SQL database service. Ref: [How to create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). We can't answer you as you searched that no information about the 1105 error.

Comment: Hi Matt Mangold, can I put this as answer?

Comment: Hi Matt, hope you're doing well. Haven't heard you for a long time, just follow up again that did you get the root cause or  any workaround from Azure Support?

Answer (score 0):

For this question, I suggest you ask Azure Support for help on Portal for your Azure SQL database service. Provide them with more details about the error. Ref: [How to create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

[image]

We haven't met this error and can't answer you. As you searched that no information about the 1105 error.

Hope this helps.